# Bending object gives it a tilt

Tags: modeling, transforms

I will ask again because I didnt get an answer last time. Im trying to bend and object (for example 90 degress turn to the left). That works fine with blender spin tool. But when I try to bend it to the left 90 degress and to give it a slight incline object slightly rotates around self and I want to avoid that.
[image]

real shape:

[image]

My failed recreation that tilts:
[image]

Comment: Did you want something like this?: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/wD1QSVDX/
If so, you might have to use the spin tool multiple time, first to rotate around the X axis and then again around the Z axis.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/zOvTHXW.png No, actualy I wanted the end bit to look like this

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your object is a bit tilted. You can simply correct the *Axis* value it in the *Operator* box:

[image]

Or you can create a new *Transform Orientation* ("+" button), to keep it selected in the panel:

[image]

Then spin the face:

[image]

But as you see it makes the shape go down on the Z axis, is it what you want? If not, you could use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Bridge Edge Loops* instead. Duplicate the face, align it with the global axis:

[image]

Use the *Bridge Edge Loops* tool, tweak the parameters in the *Operator* box:

[image]

[image]

For the second shape you show, I would do it this way:

- Create an angle:

[image]

- Move up the tip:

[image]

- Bevel the angle:

[image]

- Extrude along normals, etc...

[image]

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/G67gRch.png I tried to recreate what is in this picture,there were no problems for angles 1 and 2 but number 3 gave me problems because it rotates with slight incline and I was unable to recreate that. Im still looking at your answer because it is a litlle bit more complex but I hope that it will help me :)

Comment: ok, it looks a bit different then, I'm going to add the image you provide in your initial question

Comment: Thanks for reply but the object is too complex for this solution

Comment: I don't think so, I think bevel is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

Make the spin in the flat, and *then* <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> raise the inclined part of the frame, using *Proportional Editing, Connected, Linear falloff*?

[image]

.. before making your circular perforations, other details which have to keep their shape..